# How to use super in Java?

Tags: java, super

Can you help me how to use the super (`super.paintComponent(g);`) keyword in Java.

Can we use super keyword within the `paintComponent` method in Java? What if we use super in the main method. Is it even possible?

```
File Drawrainbow.java
package com.company;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class DrawRainbow extends JPanel {
    // define indigo and violet
    private final static Color VIOLET = new Color(128,0,128);
    private final static Color INDIGO = new Color(75,0,130);

    //colors to use in the rainbow, starting from innermost
    // the two white entries result in an empty arc in the center

    private Color[] colors ={Color.WHITE, Color.WHITE, VIOLET,INDIGO,Color.BLUE,Color.GREEN,Color.YELLOW,Color.ORANGE,Color.RED};

    //constructor
    public DrawRainbow(){
        setBackground(Color.WHITE); // set the background to while
    }

    // draws a rainbow using concentric arcs
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);

        int radius = 20; // radius of an arc

        // draw the rainbow near the bottom-center
        int centerX = getWidth()/2;
        int centerY = getHeight() - 10;

        // draws filled arcs starting with the outermost
        for (int counter = colors.length; counter > 0; counter--){
            // set the color for the current arc
            g.setColor(colors[counter-1]);

            //fill the arc from 0  to 180 degrees
            g.fillArc(centerX-counter*radius,
                    centerY-counter*radius,
                    counter*radius*2,counter*radius*2,0,180);
        }
    }
}

File Test.java


package com.company;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // write your code here

        DrawRainbow panel = new DrawRainbow();
        JFrame application = new JFrame();

        application.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        application.add(panel);
        application.setSize(400,250);
        application.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know what `super` does? If not, go look that up on Google first. Then you probably would not have this question anymore.

Comment: See: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Keywords/super

Answer (score 6):

Here:

```
> super.paintComponent(g);
```

On your `DrawRainbow` instance, you are invoking the "original" implementation of `paintComponent()` as inherited from the super class of `DrawRainbow`.

In other words: when you are facing the need to

- `@Override` a super class method
- but sometimes invoke that "original" implementation

then you use super like that.

Note: the main method is **static**. Static methods aren't inherited, thus there is no point in doing `super.main()` (or for any other static method).
And to be precise: you can't **override** static methods, if at all, you can only "shadow" them.

Instead, if you would want to do that, you could say `MySuperClass.main()` for example.

Answer (score 0):

`super` is mostly used to call the parent constructor but basically it just represents the parent class and can be used to access members of the parent class